# Docker Base Simple image : Cannot start container XXX: exec: "cat": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a base image using the following command as listed in docker documentation

https://docs.docker.com/articles/baseimages/

1) $ sudo debootstrap raring raring > /dev/null
2) $ sudo tar -C raring -c . | sudo docker import - raring
3) $ sudo docker run raring cat /etc/lsb-release

When I run command #3 I get the error FATA[0013] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 1774ff3afe4f652bcff980ba5871c50bd1987b159c1f61c5d593d05460e82512: exec: "cat": executable file not found in $PATH

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I am using Ubuntu trusty release as my base operating system and trying to use  Ubuntu raring release while creating a base image. Once I move from raring to trusty it works seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo docker run -it raring /bin/bash -c cat /etc/lsb-release`  you need to allocate a terminal

Comment: Now I get this error
FATA[0021] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container f60183a7be3c8c7b689b6bebaba9a19bfbedb3281891e61be96d95875961f18d: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory

Comment: maybe you have this problem https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7352 Can you post `docker version`  ?

Comment: Docker version 1.4.1, build 5bc2ff8

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the raring is no longer available in ubuntu repository so Command #1 itself fails and that is why #3 also fails :). I am now trying with trusty release.

Comment: I am able to make it work with trusty release..hurray :)